# Setting up to use the Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to learn how to use the Android NDK, but am new to the android environment all together, and only have little experience in C++, with no experience in C. I was criticized earlier today for a question similar to this, so I will try to make this as appropriate as possible.

I have been reading up on the NDK with the two following links: 
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/ndk-tutorial/

http://permadi.com/blog/2011/09/setting-up-android-jni-projects-in-windows-eclipse-and-sequoyah/

I have downloaded the NDK, Sequoyah, and Cygwin. It still tells me I need to update 'awk', and download GNU Make 3.81. I have looked up awk, and don't really know what it is. I am working in Eclipse with my minSDK set to 10, and in Windows 7 Professional.

What I am asking for is just an explanation of what Sequoyah, Cygwin, awk, and GNU Make are used for, and how they are used.

I'm sorry if this is not a question suitable for SO, but I don't know where else to ask it, and have so little experience with everything they talk about in the tutorials that I get very lost. If anyone knows somewhere else I can go for help other than here I'd appreciate the information.

Thanks

Comment: I'm an intern and was given a project where the NDK was needed, no one here has experience with the NDK so I have to figure it out online.

Comment: Also, I don't need to write any code in C, the company has a program already written for a palm pilot which they are hoping to switch over to Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequoyah is the part of Eclipse that handles NDK builds. The problem is that the NDK support in Sequoyah is not current. The version of ADT that is currently in Preview #3 at tools.android.com would be a better choice for you than to use Sequoyah. It handles build and debug workflows. We're planning to deprecate that functionality as soon as ADT20 ships.